# Использование IWebBrowser2

Tags: com, c++

Я пишу приложение, которое использует COM объект IWebBrowser2. Я использую IWebBrowser2 для взаимодействия с сайтом, при этом объект IWebBrowser2 невидим (put_Visible(false)). Пользователь видит только результат работы. Проблема в том, что в IE (IWebBrowser2 - это объект, представляющий IE) появляется запрос на подтверждение доступа к данной странице сайта. Хотелось бы узнать, как отключить подтверждение из кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE (IWebBrowser2) все настройки сохраняет в реестре. Для того, чтобы изменить его настройки из пользовательского кода, достаточно просто прописать нужные поля в реестре. Для решения этой задачи можно воспользоваться кодом приведенным ниже.

```
LONG SetValue(){

 char * szParamName = "PopupMgr";
 char * szValue     = "no";
 char * szKey       = "SOFTWARE\\MICROSOFT\\Internet Explorer\\New Windows";

 HKEY hKey;

 LONG lRes = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, szKey, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey) ;

 if (lRes != ERROR_SUCCESS){
    return lRes ;
 }

 lRes = RegSetValueEx(hKey, szParamName, 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE *)szValue, sizeof(char)*(strlen(szValue)+1));
 RegCloseKey(hKey);
 return lRes;

}
```

После выполнения этой функции, не будет ни одного запроса на подтверждение разрешения доступа к данной странице.